# Single page website. Redirect to home page if 404 error

Tags: seo, 404, homepage, page

I have singe page website.

So I have just only single page - home page.

If some one types `www.mysite.com/anything` into their address bar and I redirect to `home page` is this bad for SEO?

It is probably better to have separate `404` page but I am just wondering because single page sites are by their nature not perfect for SEO. Maybe if I redirect to the home page on `404` I would damage it's rankings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do understand your concern about SEO. However don't forget about your visitors: what will help them the most? A 404 or a redirect to your front page which contains all the content you have on your site. Personally I think a 404 error might break the single page user experience you're creating. However in case there is need for a 404 error, your visitors may get annoyed because they have no idea why your website isn't working.

I believe that your best option is a [301 redirect](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php). Even though a single page website may not be the best for SEO, there are enough other tactics you can and should implement.